# OneToOne shared Primary Key, Pure JPA 2.0 Solution works with EclipseLink but fails with with Hibernate Provider

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.0, eclipselink, one-to-one, shared-primary-key

Please refer 
[OneToOne between two tables with shared primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805306/onetoone-between-two-tables-with-shared-primary-key)
for the original problem.

And my answer in the same thread about a solution in Pure JPA 2.0 way (using EclipseLink Provider).

Now the issue I am facing is that once I switched the JPA provider from EclipseLink to hibernate-entitymanager 3.5.1-Final, Same example is throwing below exception:

```
    2 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.Version - Hibernate Annotations 3.5.1-Final
    11 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - Hibernate 3.5.1-Final
    13 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - hibernate.properties not found
    15 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - Bytecode provider name : javassist
    17 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - using JDK 1.4 java.sql.Timestamp handling
    94 [main] INFO org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version - Hibernate Commons Annotations 3.2.0.Final
    99 [main] INFO org.hibernate.ejb.Version - Hibernate EntityManager 3.5.1-Final
    269 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder - Binding entity from annotated class: com.nirmal.demo.jpa.eclipselink.domain.UserLogin
    298 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder - Bind entity com.nirmal.demo.jpa.eclipselink.domain.UserLogin on table USER_LOGIN
    341 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder - Binding entity from annotated class: com.nirmal.demo.jpa.eclipselink.domain.UserDetail
    342 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder - Bind entity com.nirmal.demo.jpa.eclipselink.domain.UserDetail on table USER_DETAIL
    Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: users] Unable to configure EntityManagerFactory
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:371)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:55)
        at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:78)
        at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
        at com.nirmal.demo.jpa.eclipselink.Main.main(Main.java:16)
    Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unknown mappedBy in: com.nirmal.demo.jpa.eclipselink.domain.UserLogin.userDetail, referenced property unknown: com.nirmal.demo.jpa.eclipselink.domain.UserDetail.userLogin
        at org.hibernate.cfg.OneToOneSecondPass.doSecondPass(OneToOneSecondPass.java:152)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1221)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.secondPassCompile(AnnotationConfiguration.java:383)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildMappings(Configuration.java:1206)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildMappings(Ejb3Configuration.java:1449)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.EventListenerConfigurator.configure(EventListenerConfigurator.java:193)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:1077)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:275)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:359)
        ... 4 more
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

That is because of old Hibernate version which does have a bug well described in [HHH-5695](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-5695) and fixed in [HHH-6813](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-6813).

Problem can be solved by updating to [fresh version](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hibernate/files/hibernate4/4.2.3.Final/).