# Hibernate: How to set the relations between two tables with the same sequence generated primary key?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, primary-key, sequence

I have 2 tables, T_PLN and T_PLN_CST_PRD
A generator (M2M.Q_PLN_ID) is defined in the database (Oracle) and should be used as the primary key for both tables.

While saving a new plan (which contains a CostPeriod), I want the generator to create a new primary key for T_PLN and use it in T_PLN_CST_PRD as a primary key as well.

Table T_PLN
PLN_ID // primary key (long) generated by sequence
// some more columns

Table T_PLN_CST_PRD
PLN_ID // primary key - should be same one as in T_PLN table
// some more columns

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "M2M", name = "T_PLN")
public class Plan {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "m2mPlanId", sequenceName = "M2M.Q_PLN_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "m2mPlanId")
    @Column(name = "PLN_ID")
    Long id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name = "PLN_ID", table = "T_PLN_CST_PRD")
    CostPeriod costPeriod;

    ...   
}



@Entity
@Table(schema = "M2M", name = "T_PLN_CST_PRD")
public class CostPeriod {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "PLN_ID")
    Long planId;

    ...
}
```

Code above is missing something to connect both primary keys, but I'm not sure what...

I tried all sorts of relations (@OneToOne with mappedBy, @JoinColumn, adding Plan as a member of T_PLN_CST_PRD..) but couldn't get it to work due to verious reasons:

- IdentifierGenerationException: ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save():
- IdentifierGenerationException: attempted to assign id from null one-to-one property

and others...

also tried the solution in:
[OneToOne between two tables with shared primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805306/onetoone-between-two-tables-with-shared-primary-key)
with no luck.

How should this kind of relation be defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming JPA 2+ then you be able to easily map this as below:

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "M2M", name = "T_PLN")
public class Plan {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "m2mPlanId", sequenceName = "M2M.Q_PLN_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "m2mPlanId")
    @Column(name = "PLN_ID")
    Long id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, mappedBy = "plan")
    CostPeriod costPeriod;
}



@Entity
@Table(schema = "M2M", name = "T_PLN_CST_PRD")
public class CostPeriod {

    @Id
    @OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name = "PLN_ID")
    Plan plan;
}
```

Ensure you have set both sides of the relationship before persisting.

```
plan.setCostPeriod(costPeriod);
costPeriod.setPlan(plan);
```

Comment: I though it was working, it's not failing on any error and the data is saved to the database. But the ID's are not the same. it seems that 2 different primary id's are created for the tables.

Comment: it's not working now - complains about:
"Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?"

Comment: I have checked my **original**  solution against the book ProJPA2 and I do not see anything wrong. Post the code where you create and persist the entities. I fail to see, given these mappings, how CostPeriod can possibly be created with a different ID. I mean, where can this 'other' ID be coming from?

Comment: After some investigation it seems that this was related to a DB trigger:
`select M2M.Q_PLN_ID.NEXTVAL INTO :new.PLN_ID from dual;`
which overriden the JPA query parameters and caused it to be inserted with a x+1 id. we removed it.

Answer (score 0):

I think your are missing `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` and `MapsId` for a bidirectional one-to-one shared primary key model.

Can you try the following mapping:

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "M2M", name = "T_PLN")
public class Plan {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "m2mPlanId", sequenceName = "M2M.Q_PLN_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "m2mPlanId")
    @Column(name = "PLN_ID")
    Long id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    //OR
    //Instead of above @OneToOne and @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn use below:
    //@OneToOne(mappedBy="plan", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    CostPeriod costPeriod;

    ...
}



@Entity
@Table(schema = "M2M", name = "T_PLN_CST_PRD")
public class CostPeriod {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "PLN_ID")
    Long planId;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    @MapsId
    private Plan plan;  

    ...
}
```

And while saving:

```
        Plan p = new Plan();
        CostPeriod cp = new CostPeriod();
        p.costPeriod = cp;
        cp.plan = p;
        session.persist(p);
```

Comment: Wouldn't he want mappedBy on one side of the relationship rather than defining  a join column on both sides? Additionally, adding table = "T_PLN_CST_PRD" will  not force the join column to be in T_PLN_CST_PRD. I believe table would only be specified in case of a `@SecondaryTable` being defined for CostPeriod.

Comment: @AlanHay My mistake. copy paste errors. Along with that I used IDENTITY as strategy. I like your simpler code. But then, I have updated the code. would like to hear any suggestions/comments. By the way, I didn't get your comment regarding SecondaryTable. Can you elaborate.

Comment: This will works as well. it failed for me due to the same reason as in @Alan Hay answer. (DB trigger)