# JPA - Saving new DB object containing new DB object mapped by ID

Tags: java, database, jpa, orm, mapping

My situation: I have one DB table for ***Object*** and a separate DB table for ***Object's extra info***. ***Object*** is identified by autogenerated serial ID, ***Object's extra info*** has the same value as it's PK, so there is one-to-one relation.

I mapped ***Object's extra info*** within the instance of ***Object***. It works fine for reading, but I am struggling while trying to save new record into DB.

***Object*** side reference looks like this:

```
@JoinColumn(name = "object_id", referencedColumnName = "object_id")
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private ObjectExtraInfo detail;
```

PK column in ***Object's extra info***:

```
@Id
@NotNull
@Column(name = "object_id")
private Integer objectId;
```

I am using `EntityManger.merge()`, because there are couple of other DB tables referenced, `EntityManager.persist()` would be forcing me to deal with propper identification of DB entities.

It is no problem to achieve new ***Object*** record being saved, but the best I can do with attached ***Object's extra info*** was that it appears in DB with zero as PK. The auto-generated value of the new ***Object*** record is not distributed into ***Object's extra info***. And it is impossible to change it afterwards while it is PK.

I am pretty sure my JPA annotations are messed up, especially on ***Object's extra info*** side. But so far I was unable to figure out the right approach.

Comment: You need to actually tell the JPA provider that you want to use a shared primary key model. See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805306/onetoone-between-two-tables-with-shared-primary-key or here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6833370/jpa-onetoone-with-shared-id-can-i-do-this-better or here https://dzone.com/articles/onetoone-shared-primary-key

Comment: I tried approach described in http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping-association (chapter 2.2.5.1). But I am ending up either with `"Primary key on table (object) has a field with a null key value."` error message when I use `@Column(name = "object_id")` in **Object's extra info** or with `Column (objectid) not found in any table in the query (or SLV is undefined)` when I omit it. Any idea what could be wrong?