# Spring Boot mapping issues

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, mysql-connector

This my project in Spring Boot. Can Anyone please explain me why the delete and update operations redirect to error pages but when going back to the same page, there the changes have been updated.[Github Project Link](https://github.com/vikasseervi/ezManage)

> I tried using Mapping, like @OneToOne etc. But when using its giving the error
> `com.mysql.cj.exceptions.DataConversionException: Cannot determine value type from string 'abdul'`

without even displaying the main page.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805306/onetoone-between-two-tables-with-shared-primary-key

Answer (score 0):

So as i gone through your code, I found some minor issues that were ignored
Issue occurred when you hit **"/delete"** or **"/save"** api for deleting or updating records.

**1.** under `EmployeeController.java file line number 84` -> change `return "redirect:/list";` to `return "redirect:/employees/list";`

**explanation** - because its redirecting to the list whereas it should redirect to employees/list as /list is located under employees directory.

**2.** same as above under `EmployeeController.java file line number 105` -> change `return "redirect:/list";` to `return "redirect:/employees/list";`

**3.** under `EmployeeServiceImpl.java file line number 37` method **deleteEmployeeByUsername** add **@Transactional** annotation on top of it

**explanation** - as deleting a record comes under DML so we need to use transactional management here as if any issue persist then it can rollback the transactional

**4.** under `MemberRepository.java file line number 11` instead of `Member deleteByUsername(String username);` use  v`oid deleteByUsername(String username);` only you need to replace **Manager** to **void** as it will return nothing

**explanation** - basically in `MemberServiceImpl.java line number 35` you are using void return type and in repository you using Manager as return wherein it will not return any object as we are deleting an object/record

**5.** use no agr constructor in

```
RoleId.java -

    public RoleId() {
        super();
    }
    
    and in Role.java - 
    
    public Role() {
        super();
    }
```

After changing/updating all the code run and see whether it works or not.

If any issue persist feel free to comment

Comment: Thanks for the help buddy,
But I'm still facing issues with deleting and updating(username) of existing employees which were created during creation of schema(provided in sql scripts folder).
Is there something to do with mapping annotations?
And I've updated the changes suggested by you and pushed on my github profile.

Comment: ok then will take your update and check what you have done